# How to set up Netflix payment model for an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, app-store, payment, netflix

I am close to going to market with my app but, I am struggling a little with pricing. I think the best pricing scenario would be similar to the netflix model e.g. You get the first month free **after** you enter your credit card. You then have to unsubcribe to cancel the subscription.

However, I have been researching how to do this for an iPhone app being distributed through the appstore and it seems difficult to set up. You need to have your own server and the customer needs to sign up through your website. This sounds very complicated to set up and frankly I would rather get the product to market as soon as possible.

Does anyone know of an easier way to set up a netflix style payment model? I was going to use the appstore promo codes and give them out to my target market instead, but it seems like they are only available in the US. I am based in the EU.

How can I offer my app for free for a month or so to build up a user base before starting to charge for it?

Any help you could give me on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In-app purchase? https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html